# Finding a path covering all the checkpoints

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am having a matrix  A of size`2*N` Arrays , each element is either `*` checkpoint or `X` for danger point it's not allowed to enter danger point.

You need to find if there `exist a path` that cover all the checkpoints without visiting the danger point and also each point is `visited once`.

You can start you journey at any checkpoint.

For ex:

```
*X**
***X
```

A path exist visiting all the checkpoint.

**My Approach:**

Choose the first checkpoint you encounter from 0 to N:

If you are at `index i` and other array (A[0] or A[1]) contains the chekpoint so switch the array, if not  continue in the same array if possible.

Finally Check if all checkpoints are visited.

My Approach is not giving me correct answer what's wrong here

**Code:**

```
dfs(int x , int i){
  Visted[x][i] = true;
  if(!Visted[x^1][i] && A[x^1][i] == '*')
      dfs(i, x^1);
  else if(i+1 < n && A[x][i] == '*') 
      dfs(i+1,x);
}
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear what "each point is visited once". Should this be "each point is visited no more than once"?

Comment: @n.m. perhaps it means "exactly once".

Comment: @n.m. each point should be visited exactly once

Comment: If you need to visit all points exactly once, then it isn't clear how you can avoid danger points, or what is the significance of check points. All points means all points, including danger points and check points.

Comment: @n.m. I picking the first checkpoint encounter between (0,n) and calling `DFS(i,0) or DFS(i,1)` based on which array it occur , then finding path from this point to check if all checkpoints are collected or not

Comment: I'm asking *what* problem you are trying to solve, not how you are solving it.

Comment: @n.m. The task is (most likely) to visit all _checkpoints_ exactly once, and avoid all danger points (don't visit them). Each point is either a checkpoint (`*`) or a danger point (`X`).

Comment: @n.m. above comment explain the task

Comment: @Gassa what about points that are neither? Can we visit any of them twice?

Comment: @n.m. Each point is either a checkpoint (*) or a danger point (X). It's mentioned in the first paragraph.

Comment: @JohnySins What is the answer to this test case? C stands for checkpoint. I am assuming it should be non-existent but your algorithm says it is possible. These are the first and second rows.
XXXXCX
CCCCCC

Comment: It's hard to tell where exactly your approach fails because there's no complete algorithm. Your pseudocode does something that resembles the right thing, but it doesn't look like it returns any result. Please show your actual code and input it fails to process correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, once you pick the initial point, the solution by your algorithm is either unique or non-existent, since it has at most one step to try at every cell.

So, the problem may be in the part you don't show: how do you pick the initial point?
With this algorithm, you can just try both cases and see if one of the resulting paths covers every cell.

Here are two examples.
On the left, we have to start on the first line.
On the right, we have to start on the second line.

```
*X    1X                 **    23
**    23                 *X    1X
```

Comment: @JohnySins It may be right, but difficult to say without the context. E.g., what is the range of x, what is n, do the coordinates start from zero or one, how is the function called initially. That's the problem a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would solve.

Comment: My algo works correct on both the test case.. don't know what wrong ?

Comment: @JohnySins If you want more help, you may want to post a complete program, not just a function without sufficient context. An example where it doesn't work - if you have it - would also help.

Comment: @JohnySins You may want to revisit Codechef's [Code of Conduct](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/18662/does-codechef-have-any-code-of-conduct), which you agreed to when registering for the competition. Specifically this: _Do not ask or discuss any aspect of any CodeChefs’ problem during an ongoing contest on any other platform, online or offline. Discussion of strategy should be avoided during the contest and postponed till the end._

Comment: It not an ongoing contest

Comment: @JohnySins Yeah, it already ended _when you posted the question link_ in a comment. But that is beside the point, because the contest was still running _when you asked the question_.